# Spinner Default Theme to EditText android

Tags: android, styles, android-edittext, spinner, android-theme

I have `EditText` and I want it to be shown in the same theme of Spinner , with background and arrow because I have made this `EditText` Clickable and it is open a custom popup

Answer (score 20):

Use the following style in your `EditText`:
`style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"`

For example:

`<TextView

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle" />`

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/apple">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```